# How to run an external program to python when starting django?

Tags: python, django

I would like to know if it is possible to run a python program automatically when starting the django application?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yes, it is, but what are you actually trying to do? What program is this?

Comment: Not sure if this is a good practise. But, you can update manage.py code. try putting `os.system("python {YOUR CODE.py}")` in manage.py

Comment: @InAFlash `manage.py` won't be used by application servers such as gunicorn or uwsgi, so that won't do anything when running in production.

Comment: Ah! got it. when deployed this won't work. It will work when running locally using `python manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: Well yes, but `os.system()` will block the script – `subprocess.Popen()` would be closer, but still, I'd prefer knowing what OP actually wants here :)

Comment: Agreed. Popen is better.

Comment: I want to display on a page a graph, so I have a python sscript that retrieves the necessary information from a database and builds a graph with plot.ly. However, I have called this function in my view and therefore loading the page takes a lot of time. I thought then when starting apache (because I host it with apache2 and wsgi) that it would run the script as a thread and loop back every 10 minutes.

Comment: You should probably just look into periodically running the graph-generating script in the background using e.g. a cronjob or a systemd timer, then.

Comment: It's complicate to explain. The project will be moved to another system, for a school. And I would really like there to be a parallel execution solution in django